# how to use javascript to load scr for video/mp4 in videojs using specific id for the video

Tags: html5-video, video.js

```
  <video id="example" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="511" height="382" poster="" data-setup="{}">  
    <source src=""  type="video/mp4">

  </video>
<script>
```

I want to able to load the source for an mp4 using JavaScript using two different sources.  One will be the default, and the other will be fallback in case the first source is down.  I'm using videojs version 4.7, and I have multiple videos.  All of the sources will be coming from one JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at the "src" method of the VideoJS API: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#src-source-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made an HD toggle plugin for [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) in which I have used JavaScript to load sources. 
I think this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hussnain1/ctLmx4fz/1/) would surely help you. It's used just as simply as that:

```
HDtoggle('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4','http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4');
```

You can modify the library in fiddle according to your needs.

Comment: Toggle is good option but i was thinking of javascript to automatically detect if the first link is broken then it will play the second link by itself.